# convert float to datetime when month is decimal place (YYYY.MM float)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my data:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'date': [2021.01, 2021.02, 2021.03, 2021.04],
                   'value': [2, 3, 4, 1]})

d
```

[image]

I want to convert the date column to date. It is currently float with months in decimal place (YYYY.mm)

This does not work:

```
pd.to_datetime(d['date'], format='%Y.%m', errors='coerce').dt.to_period('m')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply by 100 and use an integer as input for [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```py
pd.to_datetime(d['date'].mul(100).astype(int), format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')
```

*NB. it seems to work even without conversion to integer, but I would still do it, or use `round` to avoid floating point ambiguity (depending on the wanted output)*

output:

```
0    2021-01
1    2021-02
2    2021-03
3    2021-04
Name: date, dtype: period[M]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d.loc[:,'date']=pd.to_datetime(d.date.astype(str), format='%Y.%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
d

     date  value
0  2021-01      2
1  2021-02      3
2  2021-03      4
3  2021-04      1
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.